# How to rollback the initial migration in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, rollback

How to rollback the initial migration in EF?

I created the first migration on a brand new database using Entity Framework Core 6.0.
As usual, it created an `Up` section which perform the migration, and the `Down`  section to revert it.

In EF, one do `update-database <my_migration>` to update a DB accordingly with the migrations, and `my_migration` is the target migration. Simple command which also allow to rollback to a previous migration.

My question is simple, how to rollback the very first migration? (as there's no migration before this one, which could have been specified to the command described before).
Though, the `Down`  section containing all the needed instructions (to remove all tables created in the `Up` section, in my case) exists, so can it be called? and how?
Thanks